# Calling nested overloaded function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given a nested overloaded function, such as `innerOverloaded` below, what is the best way to call it from a parent overloaded function that has similarly overloaded parameters as the inner one, as in the case with `overloadedWithError`?

It seems that TypeScript can't figure out that the types are covariant (using the term somewhat loosely here).

```
function innerOverloaded(foo: true): false;
function innerOverloaded(foo: false): true;
function innerOverloaded(foo: boolean): boolean {
  return !foo;
}

function overloadedWithError(foo: boolean): boolean {
  return innerOverloaded(foo);
}

function overloadedButUgly(foo: boolean): boolean {
  return foo ? innerOverloaded(foo) : innerOverloaded(foo);
}

function overloadedButLessUgly(foo: boolean): boolean {
  return innerOverloaded(foo as true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`boolean` is a union `true | false`, as any union TS needs something to narrow it down.

There is an [open ticket about this : #14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).